# Unexpected output in C from float multiply

Tags: c, floating-point

I am performing a multiplication and addition operation in C and am getting the wrong result.

I am performing the following operation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{
    float** fpimag;
    float** fpreal;

    // Some code to assign fpimag and fpreal
    // fpimag and fpreal are two dimensional arrays that are
    // passed by reference to some functions to assign data to them
    allocatememory(&fpimag,&fpreal);
    storedata(&fpimag,&fpreal);


    autofunction(&fpimag,&fpreal);
} // main()

void autofunction(float*** fpimag,float***fpreal) {
    float expreal;
    float expimag;

    expreal = cos((*afph_correct)[row][column]);
    expimag = sin((*afph_correct)[row][column]);

    (*fpimag)[row][column] = (*fpimag)[row][column] * expreal + (*fpreal)[row][column] * expimag;

 printf("Operation looks like this\n");
 printf("%f*%f + %f*%f\n",(*fpimag)[row][column],expreal,(*fpreal)[row][column],expimag);
 printf("The value is %f\n",(*fpimag)[row][column]);
} // autofunction
```

This is the output I get:

```
Operation looks like this
-0.003095*-0.431162 + 0.000027*-0.902275
The value is 0.003865
```

However the correct answer should be:

```
0.0013101
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to post the relevant parts of the code. I.E. the portion where you are printing...

Comment: K thank you for the suggestion, I updated my question to reflect your suggestion

Comment: OK. Now it's better. Could you now post the place where you are assigning the values?

Comment: hey @pablo-santa-cruz I updated it now

Comment: You are printing the addresses of your arrays, but interpreted as floating point numbers. This is not the calculation performed in the code. (But the precision has nothing to do with the problem.)

Comment: @UncleO, thank you for your suggestion, but this is because I tried to simplify my code for my post.  In my actual code I did the print statement properly.  I have since updated the post.  So basically the problem still exists and that was just a typo on my post, not in my actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the problem it was pretty obvious:

I was overwriting the value of fpreal and then trying to use it in another calculation.

Thus I did:

```
(*fpreal)[row][column] = (*fpreal)[row][column]*expreal - (*fpimag)[row][column]*expimag;
(*fpimag)[row][column] = (*fpimag)[row][column]*expreal + (*fpreal)[row][column]*expimag;
```

I have since updated the code so that the values of fpreal and fpimag are stored in some temporary variables and use those for the calculations, as such:

```
oldreal = (*fpreal)[row][column];
oldimag = (*fpimag)[row][column];

(*fpreal)[row][column] = oldreal*expreal - oldimag*expimag;
(*fpimag)[row][column] = oldimag*expreal + oldreal*expimag;
```

Thank you everybody for your assistance though!

Answer (score 0):

Try long double, more precise than float:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double

Please note that you should change your printf (%Lf for long double)

Comment: hey @amir-pincovici how do I declare a long double?

Comment: Replace "flout" with "long double". Also, I now noticed that your original printf is wrong. Try printf("%f*%f + %f*%f\n",(*fpimag)[row][column],expreal,(*fpreal)[row][column],expimag);

Comment: Amir is right, in that you are printing the addresses of your arrays, but interpreted as floating point numbers. This is not the calculation performed in the code. (But the precision has nothing to do with the problem.)

Comment: I accidentally wrote my print statement wrong here, originally i simplified the code on this site, but in my actual code I did the print statement properly, I will update the code now

Comment: No one has given me a correct answer yet.  Just an FYI, all of the REAL part of the calculations are correct.  But when I do this operation shown above to get the imaginary part, the answer is wrong!

Comment: @starbox: I feel like there is something missing in the code. For example: you print (*fpimag)[row][column] twice, and in each time you get different answer printed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it doesn't crash. In fact I'm surprised it even compiles. I would be gobsmacked if it compiles without warnings.

- No memory is allocated for fpreal and fpimag.
- Values in fpreal are used before being initialised.
- Uses two dimensional array access but doesn't give any dimensions.
- Prints out pointers fpreal and fpimag as floats.
- Tries to print out the values as they were before the operation but value in fpimag has been overwritten.

(The first two may be covered by code not shown - the other three look to be definite problems)

Comment: I left out the memory allocation for the sake of simplicity, obviously my memory is allocated and values are assigned, I mentioned that in my main() comments.  Thank you for your concern though, but none of these answers is correct

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following two lines:

```
(*fpimag)[row][column] = (*fpimag)[row][column] * expreal +
                         (*fpreal)[row][column] * expimag;
printf("%f*%f + %f*%f\n",fpimag,expreal,fpreal,expimag);
```

Can't you see that fpimag is not the same as (*fpimag)[row][column]? (and the same with fpreal) You are writing pointer to float pointer values, not the values the pointers are pointing to. Try this instead:

```
float imag = (*fpimag)[row][column];
float real = (*fpreal)[row][column];
(*fpimag)[row][column] = imag * expreal + real * expimag;
printf("%f*%f + %f*%f\n",imag,expreal,real,expimag);
```

Comment: I already fixed this, my first version of my post left out the fact that fpimag and fpreal were actually two dimensional arrays.  When someone asked me to show how I assigned values and such, I forgot to update this print statement, but it is updated on the site now.  So basically, this isn't the problem, I'm surprised everybody keeps thinking inside the box

Comment: @magnus-skog, i updated the post to reflect how my code actually is.  I originally simplified my two dimensional arrays to just variable names because that was just details the people didn't need to know about.  I updated the post now, but that wasn't the issue, I did this correctly in my actual code